# How do we obtain the column space from the REF of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am not given the original matrix. I am only given the row echelon form of the original matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&-1\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

I was able to notice that the reduced row echelon form has the form:

\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

which is essentially, \begin{bmatrix}0|I\end{bmatrix}

Typically, it is not possible to obtain the column space of a matrix by just analysing the row echelon form because elementary row operations change the column space of the matrix as we bring it to the row echelon form. However, I think this special matrix allows us to do that. The question I was given says that it is possible but I'm unsure of how to achieve it. I would greatly appreciate any assistance on this. Thanks!

Comment: The point here is that the column space is a $3$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$, hence all of $\Bbb R^3$, regardless of the original matrix.

Comment: @TedShifrin Got it. Thanks!